# javascript replace i into I

Tags: javascript, replace

I need a javascript to replace i into I. This should apply to cases such as

- i'm good.
- So am i.
- He though i love him.

The standard `ThisContent = ThisContent.replace("i", "I");` doesn't work because it replaces every i. I also thought of `ThisContent = ThisContent.replace(" i ", " I ");` but it doesn't work for the first and second case.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
ThisContent = ThisContent.replace(/\bi\b/g, "I");
```

Here `\b` indicates a "word boundary", so only word-like `i`'s will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks. How about a word, say bing. I want to replace it with Bing. The above function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `.replace(/\bi\b/g, "I").replace(/\bbing\b/g, "Bing")`